# Как правильно использовать фильтр term_link с sitemap.xml для категорий товаров WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sitemap

Добрый день!
Дли изменения url категории товаров в WooCommerce использую следующую функцию:

```
add_filter( 'term_link', array( $this, 'replace_term_link' ), 9000, 2);

function replace_term_link ( $termlink, $term ) {
    if( $term->taxonomy == 'product_cat' ) {
      $permalinks = (array)get_option( 'product_cat_custom_permalinks' ); 

      if( array_key_exists( (int)$term->term_id, $permalinks ) )
        $termlink = empty( $permalinks[$term->term_id] ) ? $termlink : $permalinks[$term->term_id];
    }

    return $termlink;
  }
```

Генерирую карту сайта плагином Google XML Sitemaps при просмотре карты категории товаров измененные категории выводятся относительными ссылками /product_cat/myproductcat/ как исправить проблему? необходимо чтобы в карте сайта ulr были абсолютными

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте строку `$termlink = site_url() . $termlink;`

```
add_filter( 'term_link', array( $this, 'replace_term_link' ), 9000, 2);

function replace_term_link ( $termlink, $term ) {
    if( $term->taxonomy == 'product_cat' ) {
      $permalinks = (array)get_option( 'product_cat_custom_permalinks' ); 

      if( array_key_exists( (int)$term->term_id, $permalinks ) )
        $termlink = empty( $permalinks[$term->term_id] ) ? $termlink : $permalinks[$term->term_id];
        $termlink = site_url() . $termlink;
    }

    return $termlink;
}
```

Comment: Отказался от Google XML Sitemaps, - реализовал с помощью Yolast - у него с хуками попроще